# Equation with complex numbers and 2 variables

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation:

```
 eq = 1 + ( 9 / ( s*(s + 9) ) )*( k/(s + b) ) == 0;
```

where `s == -2 + 2I` (`I` is the imaginary unit).  I know it can be solved by separating into real and imaginary parts, substituting the value of `s` and then equating both equations to zero and solving the simultaneous equations to find the values of `b` and `k`. But how do I make *Mathematica* do this for me cause it takes very long on paper.

For those that have a similar problem, this worked for me:

```
FindInstance [{ComplexExpand[Re[eq]] == 0,  ComplexExpand[Im[eq]] == 0}, {k, b}, Reals]

{{k -> 9.04063, b -> 5.54344}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  When posting a question, please make sure you make it clear at which point you got stuck in solving this task.  What have you tried so far?  If you are new to Mathematica, did you search for "equation solving" in the documentation?

Comment: [Link to cross post on W Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/122071;jsessionid=8ACE7DC61B3B0305EAB717D3E546117B.wlp2?p_p_auth=MP1DYm7G)

Comment: There are 2 variables (`b`, `k`) and a single equation, so there will be infinitely many solution.

Comment: Is it possible to have mathematica give me at least one solution for b and k? I dont this by hand and got b = 5.54 and k =9.04, so how can i get mathematica to give me something like this. thanks

Comment: Take a look at `FindInstance`, it will try to find a solution.

Comment: Yes that worked very well, thanks Szabolcs. It gave me {{k -> -1.87205 - 5.93764 I, b -> 0}}, how do I tell Mathematica to  try to give me real values only, as I found by before. For example I want it to try to give me something like b= 5.54 and k =9.04, so no imaginary numbers.

Comment: Can you please make your question more precise and tell us exactly what you want, and how your tried to achieve it so far?  You did not say that b and k need to be reals.  Stating the question precisely will save effort for those who answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is just specifying that the variables are real:

```
Solve[eq && k \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals, {k, b}]

(* ==> {{k -> 424/45, b -> 28/5}} *)
```

`Reduce` also works in place of `Solve`.